# Set Content-Type created file with Ruby File?

Tags: ruby, file, file-io, amazon-s3, content-type

I'm using `File.open` to create a `.csv` file on the fly.

But what I need to do is set the `Content-Type` of the file to `binary/octet-stream` so that the browser will automatically download it instead of just displaying the contents of it in the browser.

The file itself is created locally and then uploaded to Amazon S3.

Comment: How are you serving this file? Are you using rack?

Comment: You can set the content type when uploading the file to S3, what library are you using to do this?

Comment: Paperclip, which uses AWS S3.

Comment: S3 just uses the content type you set on upload. If paperclip is too complex, use the official AWS-sdk ruby gem. It works well. The reason I say this is that if you are using paperclip ONLY for this one purpose, then it may be overkill.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Short Answer

There is no way to specify a `Content-Type` value in the filesystem when you create your file. In fact, this is probably not the best way to achieve your goal.

In order to suggest that a browser download a file rather than displaying it, you can leave `Content-Type: text/csv` and add the header `Content-Disposition: attachment` or `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<your custom filename>.csv` to change the filename in the "Save As..." dialog.

## Setting `Content-Disposition` using Paperclip and AWS::S3

To set the `Content-Disposition` header using Paperclip, you can add a key to your `has_attached_file` definition: [`s3_headers`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.4.5/Paperclip/Storage/S3).

```
has_attached_file :spreadsheet,
  :path => 'perhaps/a/custom/path/:class/:id/:filename',
  :or_maybe => 'other parameters',
  :s3_headers => { 'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment' }
```

### Content-Type issues

By default, a file with the extension `.csv` should be classified as a `text/csv` file. You can check this with `Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension('csv').to_s # => "text/csv"`. If this is not the case, you can add text/csv as a custom mime-type by creating a `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` file and adding:

```
Mime::Type.register 'text/csv', :csv
```

However, this should almost always not be the case (unless Windows does something funky with content types; I've only tested in Linux).

## Examples

I've put up two examples that you can check. The first is a CSV file uploaded with a `text/plain` mime-type which forces the browser to show it in-browser without downloading (my browser downloaded `text/csv` files).

https://s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow-demo/demo.csv

The second also has a mime-type of `text/plain`, but I added a header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mycustomname.csv"`

https://s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow-demo/demo-download.csv

You'll notice that the first link is displayed in browser, while the second link is downloaded with the custom name `mycustomname.csv`.

To learn why, look at the headers using `curl -I`.

```
$ curl -I https://s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow-demo/demo-download.csv
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mycustomname.csv"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

versus

```
$ curl -I https://s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow-demo/demo.csv
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Note: unrelated headers were removed.

Comment: This is becoming one hell of an answer, props to you!

Comment: Benjamin, I'm using Paperclip, which makes use of AWS-S3.

Comment: @BenoitGarret Thanks. Is there anything else you think should be added?

Comment: @BenjaminManns yep, paperclip uses the mime-type gem, find out how to override the default ones and the problem will be solved.

Comment: @BenjaminManns You win some sort of "holy crap i love you" award. Spot on and one of the most helpful answers I've ever received on SO.

Comment: @BenjaminManns The basename and extension dont seem to work in s3headers `s3_headers: { "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename = :basename.:extension" }`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ruby on Rails, you may use [`send_data`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data) method:

```
send_data csv_data, :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present', :disposition => "attachment; filename=some_csv_file.csv"
```

Comment: The file is hosted on Amazon S3, so I can't use send_data. I really need to be able to set the content type on file creation.

Comment: What? `Content-Type` on creation? Are you sure?

Comment: Your method works for hosting files with Rails, but I believe @Shpigford is creating a CSV file in Ruby that he is copying to S3 (with which program, I am not sure). However, this answer has valuable information that I don't think deserves a down vote.